# Viewdidappear equivalent method in android

Tags: android

In android i need to check files exist every time when the app is launched,i need to know the method in android which will be called when the app is launched,on create is called once when app is deployed first,but i need check each time when app is relaunched again?

Comment: well FYI onCreate is called everytime your class is created. So, whenever your activity is launched it'll be called

Comment: Hi,yes when activity is launched oncreate will be called,but if i go back to first activity from second activity,oncreate method in first activity will be called again right?

Comment: in that case.. you might want to have a look at onResume() method of activity. It is called each time you activity appears, either by creation or by navigating back from other activity.

Comment: i think he mean by app is the Main View please check my answer witch may help.

Answer (score 2):

**Oncreate** Method of your first activity will call everytime when application launch.so, put below code for checking file existance.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

    File f = new File(filePathString);
   if(f.exists())
   { 
     /* do something */ 
   }
   else
   {
      /* do something */ 
   }
```

Comment: Hi,In android is there any overriden method which will be called every time when activity is called?

Comment: @DivyaPriya: use `onResume` method which will be called everytime even if you are handling orientation by yourself or whenever your app comes to foreground.